# how to sign soup request with x509 Certificate and sha256 algorithm in c#

Tags: c#, wsdl, webclient, x509certificate, x509certificate2

The problem is that X509Certificate2 class (which is in classes genereted with wsdl file) uses by default sha1 algorithm.

Edit:

Code looks like this:

```
mLegService.mLegServiceClient client = new mLegService.mLegServiceClient("mLegServicePort");


mLegService.CreateOrderRequest request = new mLegService.CreateOrderRequest()
{
     requestHeader = new myService.RequestHeader() { institutionId = 123, requestId = "aeacbff8-ba6d-4a01-8e76-0b4384c24721", system = "XYZ" }
};

            
var cert = new X509Certificate2(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "//cert.p12", "Pass123");

client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;

myService.CreateOrderResponse response = client.createOrder(request);


txtResult.Text = response.order.name;
```

In the binding I got set of algorithms:
[image]

When there should be:

[image]

Comment: Certificates don't directly sign things, and the RSA objects ask for what algorithm to use -- there is no default.  Maybe you're having trouble at some higher layer.  But in order to really help you'd need to explain more what you've done and what you wanted to happen (vs what did happen).

Comment: I added some code in edit. The problem is that external service got certificate uses sha1 algorithm when it should use sha256. When I look to the the binding->Security->Message->AlgorithSuite I can see that there is wrong set of default algorithms. (Image in the edit)

Comment: That seems like you need to change something on binding.Security(.Message).  It's nothing about the X509Certificate2 class.

Comment: @bartonjs you're right. The problem I got is about binding.Security(.Message). 
Unfortunately I still can't send any request. :/

Comment: can you send full code

Answer (score 0):

The problem I got wasn't connected with `X509Certificate2` class, but with `binding.Security.Message`. It is the place where configuration must be changed.

Comment: when you do solve the issue, make sure to come back and edit the answer with the full details of the solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).